# Biber/Biblatex Automatically Coercing International Letters

Tags: biblatex, biber

> How can I configure `biber`/`biblatex` so that `{\"u}` is printed as `{\"u}` in the `bbl` file, not as `ü`?

I uses `biblatex`+`biber`. Because they're stuck in the past, arXiv require a `bbl` file of version `2.8`. I have an old version of `biber`, namely `2.7`, which outputs a `bbl` files with version `2.8`.
My issue is with international (non-English) letters. I have some letters like `ü`/etc in my bibliography. When I preview on arXiv, these letters simply aren't printed. (They are in the `bbl` file as `ü`/etc.) So I went through my *entire* reference set (managed with Zotero) and replaced `ü` with `\"u` and so on. (That was fun use of time `;)`!) However, when I run `biber`, even though in the `bib` file the information is stored as `\"u`, the created `bbl` file coerces this to `ü` -- which then does not get printed by arXiv.

Ideally, `biber` would take `ü` as an input and output `{\"u}`, but this seems a bit too much to ask... (Actually, ideally arXiv would be more modern, but that's also a bit too much to ask!)

As I said, I am using `biber 2.7`. I combine this with `biblatex 3.3`.

Comment: the letters should work, do you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (required for older latex formats)

Comment: Thanks, @David, for your response. I do not, no. Does that have other effects that I should be aware of?

Comment: for older latex formats you can not use any non-ascii input unless you use `inputenc` package, after 2018 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is essentially pre-loaded.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks. I have just added that one line to the preamble, and they are now printing. All those changes I made were pointless `:O` you live and learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't disagree that setting up LaTeX for UTF-8 input is the best solution, but in case you are still interested in an answer to the question as asked, you will want to use the `biblatex` option `safeinputenc` (or the Biber command line option `--output-safechars`). (Note that this works even if the input is Unicode. Biber converts all input to Unicode anyway and this option just asks it to write the output in escaped-LaTeX-macro lingo.)

Then

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, safeinputenc]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Hümphréý Äppleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

becomes

```
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{un=0,uniquepart=base,hash=859f5cb9ba8ee819b7ee027f53fbba50}{%
       family={\"{A}ppleby},
       familyi={\"{A}\bibinitperiod},
       given={H\"{u}mphr\'{e}\'{y}},
       giveni={H\bibinitperiod},
       givenun=0}}%
  }
```

in the `.bbl` file.

Comment: +1 next you'll be suggesting that people answering questions tagged biblatex and biber ought to know something about at least one of those:-)

Answer (score 3):

The letters should work, but you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` on older latex formats. (UTF-8 is the default in current latex formats)

Comment: David, thank you for this, but I have changed the acceptance tick to moewe's answer, as it does technically answer my question better. However, as noted on their answer, I'll probably set up with utf8 anyway, so thank you very much! :)

Comment: @SamT I'll survive the loss:-)